# First order logic equivalence

Tags: logic

Given some initial formula, a Universe $U$ and a model $A$ for this formula I arrived at the statement $A(\neg(\forall x F)) = 1$. How could I transform this without using any theorems, just by the semantics of $\neg$ and $\forall$ into $A_{[x\rightarrow u]}(F) = 0$ for some $u \in U$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really is nothing more than that -- unpacking the definitions of semantics of the two operators:

$\def\iff{\Leftrightarrow\ }
\phantom{\iff} A(\neg \forall x F)) = 1\\
\iff A(\forall x F)) = 0 \quad \text{(def. $\neg$)}\\
\iff \text{not:} \text{ for all } u \in U: A_{|x \to u|}(F) = 1 \quad \text{(def. $\forall$)}\\
\iff \text{for some } u \in U: A_{|x \to u|}(F) = 0 \quad \text{(paraphrasing)}
$

The last two steps implicitly include complementarity of $1$ and $0$, i.e. swapping between $0$ and $1$ by prepending resp. removing "$\text{not}$" on the conditions. This can be taken for granted, given that the definitions are of the form "$\ldots = 1$ if some condition, else $ = 0$"; the "$\text{else}$" part makes for the "$\text{not}$".

Comment: I apparently was completely blind, thanks!

Comment: but why is the second equivalence correct (first to second step)? I don't see why "F is not true for all x" is equivalent to "F is false for all x" ... Because not for all x only means that there exists such a x that F is not true, but that doesn't mean that F is never true

Comment: It nowhere says "$F$ is false for all $x$". The second step says that "$\forall x F$ is false" is equivalent to "It is not the case that for all $u$, $F$ is true". This is the  negative case of the definition of $\forall$: $A(\forall x F) = 1$ if $A_{|x \to u|}(F) = 1$ for all $x$, and $A(\forall x F) = 0$ else, i.e. if not for all $u$, $A_{|x \to u|}(F) = 1$.

Comment: I got a thinking mistake I just recognised: I thought that the second one reads as "F is false for all x" but I disregarded the formal definition. Thanks a lot for clearing me up

Comment: Yes; the "not" only negates the universality, it does not assert that $F$ is false for all $u$.